# List<String> to String - Join to a comma and quotes

Tags: apex

To do a Join From List to a String separated with commas we need to do the following:

```
String someStringVar = String.join(SomeList, ',');
```

But If I want to make a Join with Comma and Quotes?

For Example :

```
 List<String> StringList = new List<String>{'1','2','3'};
```

and the ouput should be :

```
'ag03','ag05','ag06','ag07','ag08','ag09','ag10','ex01','ex02','hu01'
```

as one String.

I'm asking that because I want to make a query on multi picklist.

****EDIT : Base on the Answer of @Mariia Illarionova ****

**For querying a multi picklist field :**

```
 String StringVar= '\'' + String.join(asd, '\',\'') + '\'';
    List<Object__c> inti = [SELECT Id,Agriculture__c FROM Interest__c WHERE Active__c = true AND  Agriculture__c INCLUDES (:StringVar)];
```

Which does not work

But this is Work:

```
List<Object__c> inti = [SELECT Id,Agriculture__c FROM Interest__c WHERE Active__c = true AND  Agriculture__c INCLUDES ('ag03','ag05','ag06','ag07','ag08','ag09','ag10','ex01','ex02','hu01')];
```

Can anyone tell me why please?

Comment: Your edit should probably be its own question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's quite a simple solution for this (also with join as you stated):

```
List<String> stringList = new List<String>{'1','2','3'};

String result = '\'' + String.join(stringList, '\',\'') + '\'';

system.debug(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this is work.
I just updated the question I would like if you can answer to the related update.
Thanks!

Comment: be careful with behaviour, when list is empty, it will return just two single-quotes.

Comment: @Salvation I have answered this question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266328/multipicklist-query/266343#266343